# msg.member is null after messageReactionAdd event

Tags: javascript, node.js, null, discord, discord.js

When somebody reacts on my server, it fires the messageReactionAdd event.
But I can't get the member object of the author of a message somebody reacted to:

```
module.exports = async (client, messageReaction, user) => {
    if (messageReaction.partial) await messageReaction.fetch();
    messageReaction.message.channel.messages.fetch();
    const msg = messageReaction.message;

    if (!msg.guild || user.bot) return;

    msg.guild.members.fetch();

    console.log(msg.member.id);
```

Error message: "Cannot read property 'id' of null"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can see this : https://gist.github.com/koad/316b265a91d933fd1b62dddfcc3ff584#file-discordjs-cheatsheet-js-L244

Comment: not sure how this should help me?

Comment: The message was probably sent in a dm

Comment: no it wasn't I am the one reacting on my server to messages and by that trying out the code. btw my code prevents dms (!msg.guild) return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

`if (await msg.guild.members.fetch(user.author.id)) return`